# Circuit amplifying a position sensitive detector

Tags: amplifier

I have a position sensitive detector (PSD), [S3979](http://sales.hamamatsu.com/assets/pdf/parts_S/S3979_etc.pdf), which outputs a small current. I'm trying to amplify this current so that it becomes measureable. The circuit below can amplify sinus waves using a function generator, but I doesn't appear to work for the PSD.

What's wrong, how can it be fixed?

[image: psd]

Comment: C1 is blocking the current from the PSD!

Comment: I'm not very familiar with PSDs, but some quick searching suggests even with C1 removed, this is not the way to connect to a PSD. See the google images results for "PSD amplifier schematic" for a few examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cap has to go.  The diode needs to be reverse biased, and with the cap in place, its not.  Do you have the Anode going to ground, or the cathode?  It should be the anode.  Also, R1 should probably be removed.  Your photodiode is functioning as a current source which will generate a voltage through the feedback resistor alone.  R1 does nothing but generate another voltage drop which will lower the back biasing of your photodiode.

Comment: Tested it out, and it appears to work. But now I have a new problem I didn't have while I still thought the cathode was going to ground. The PSD has three legs. Two are anodes. I was going to amplify both anode-cathode pairs by building two amplifying circuits and then connect them to a common ground and use the same power source. But now that both anodes go to that common ground, how can I amplify both these two currents?

Comment: Put a reverse bias voltage on the photodiode. With no light, it acts like a diode, and no current flows. With light, current can flow proportional to the light.

Comment: Then don't reverse bias and ground the common cathode.  The difference can be seen in http://physlab.lums.edu.pk/images/1/10/Photodiode_circuit.pdf  Be careful, however about adding any bias at all.  Just ground the non-inverting input of your TL071 instead of putting it at 1 volt like you're doing now.

Comment: @ScottSeidman, Nice link. Wouldn't putting the common cathode to 10V give them good reverse bias? And then the 1 volt at the inverting input would not be a problem. I don't see the worry about 'adding any bias at all'.

Comment: Yup @BobbiBennett--  that should do it.  I was just taking a shortcut through, making sure my advice wouldn't compromise dynamic range even more than zero bias by adding bias in the wrong direction, or making myself go look up the max reverse bias (which is 20V, in this case -- good to go).

Comment: That's not one volt, that's volt meter one (symbol and label courtesy of the circuit making software)

Comment: I was talking about the voltage you would read on the noninverting input of the op-amp, 10V * (100ohms)/(1Kohm + 100 Ohm)= 0.909 Volts.

Comment: I see, thank you a lot for your help I will try this out as soon as I can.

Comment: It worked. You definitely made my day! :)

Answer (score 1):

google yields this: [On-Trak - Detector-Amplifiers](http://www-cdr.stanford.edu/madefast/catalogs/on-trak/psd/psd.html)

As I said in a comment, these are not usually used as photovoltaic diodes, but as reverse biased photo-diodes. The schematic in the link above makes that pretty clear.

They are actually pretty cool devices, giving a signal that tracks a laser dot's (or any light dot) position by delivering the photocurrent current proportional to how close the dot is to an anode. I have used them before. Even with a dot that could not be resolved by eye, they give a good position by averaging the light intensity profile.

Although you will get a voltage on the diode when light hits it, that is not  usually how they are used. Set it up with reverse bias, and set your op-amp up for current input, as Scott Seidman said (the current amp part, not the tie anode to ground part).

Check out the On-Trak schematics:
[image]
Almost certainly those op-amps have power rails above and below ground, though, and in your schematic your negative rail is ground, so your 1v on the + input is correct.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the AC coupling is the problem. In which case, eliminate C1 and return the position sensor cathode to your "analog Gnd" (junction of R3 and R4) rather than the negative supply rail. This ensures the input voltage is within the valid range for the TL071.

It would also be a good idea to reduce noise by decoupling this "analog Gnd" with a 10uf capacitor to 0V.